# Centering wide div inside a thinner mask div

Tags: css, html, position, center, masking

I'm trying to center a wide div inside a smaller one, and center it. Can this be done?

I've got this:

HTML

```
<body>
<div id="full_container">
<div id="machine_mask">
<div id="machine_container">
<!---- SOME CONTENT HERE --->
</div>
</div>
<div class="machine_footer">
<img src="sprites/base_maquina.png" alt="panel de control" />
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
body {
    margin :0;
}
div#full_container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #805080;
}
div#machine_mask {
    margin-top: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 600px;
    background: #805080;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
div#machine_container {
    width: 1230px;
    height: 500px;
    background: #805080;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

When the window is wider than 1230px, it centers, but I really need for it to be centered when the window is smaller...

Is there a way to do this? (I was thinking about using jQuery and repositioning it, but I'd really prefer to do this in css)

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the absolute positioning hack.

```
div#machine_container {
    width: 1230px;
    height: 500px;
    background: #805080;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -615px; //half of 1230px
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I couldn't comment it when you posted it, but this helped me big time!

Comment: This comes like 100 years late, but I found a better solution for content with dynamic height or width: top:50%;left:50%;transform(translate(-50%,-50%));

Comment: @SebiSanchez well yeah. That was 3 and a half years ago :P flexbox would be the best solution.